# Immutable.js - Adding/updating a value into a list nested in a map

Tags: javascript, nested, immutable.js, immutablelist

Im using Immutable.js to try to add objects into lists that are nested in an object. Ive been able to get my first function `handleRecieveLeads()` to work to set the leads passed in. My second function `handleSaveLeads()` is not working properly.

From what I can see so far by logging things out is that the new item that is being pushed into that Immutable List is being over written. So when I log it to the console you only see the last item that was pushed and the one that was there before is gone.  Heres a link to JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/fugajofaxi/edit?js,console

```js
//Initial state
var state = Immutable.Map();

//sample lead
var leads = [{document_id: "L4234234234234",
              company_name: "someComp",
              date_filed:"083815",
              address:"11111 sw 123 ave",
              first_name: "john",
              last_name: "doe"
             },
             {document_id: "L11111111",
              company_name: "CorpComp",
              date_filed:"091919", 
              address:"22222 sw 456 Ave",
              first_name: "jane",
              last_name: "doe"
             }];

//Adds the new leads to the state
function handleRecieveLeads (state, leads) {
    var newState = state.set('leads', Immutable.List(leads));
    return console.log(newState.toJS());
}

handleRecieveLeads(state, leads);

//sample lead to save
var saveLeads = [{document_id: "L1919191919",
                  company_name: "someComp2",
                  date_filed:"083815",
                  address:"33333 SW 333rd Ave",
                  first_name: "dallas",
                  last_name: "thomas"
                 }];

//add leads to the savedLeads
function handleSaveLead (state, lead) {
    if(!state.savedLeads) {
        var newState = state.set('savedLeads', Immutable.List(lead));
        return console.log(newState.toJS());
    } else {
        var newState2 = state.get('savedLeads').push(lead);
        return console.log(newState2.toJS());
    }
}
//sample lead to save 2
var saveLeads2 = [{document_id: "L16161616",
                   company_name: "someComp3",
                   date_filed:"083815",
                   address:"444444 sw 555 Ave",
                   first_name: "crystal",
                   last_name: "mentos"
                  }];

handleSaveLead(state, saveLeads);

//setting a new initial state
var state2 = Immutable.fromJS({leads:leads, savedLeads: saveLeads});

handleSaveLead(state2, saveLeads2);
```

Comment: I just updated the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things going on here. 
First you never return the new 'modified' states from your handlers.

Second, `state.savedLeads` is always undefined. Use `state.get('savedLeads')` instead

Third, when you use `state.get('savedLeads')` and push the new item you want to set it in the state and return the new state from that.

Here, try this:

```
//Initial state
var state = Immutable.Map();

//sample lead
var leads = [{document_id: "L4234234234234",
              company_name: "someComp",
              date_filed:"083815",
              address:"11111 sw 123 ave",
              first_name: "john",
              last_name: "doe"
             },
             {document_id: "L11111111",
              company_name: "CorpComp",
              date_filed:"091919", 
              address:"22222 sw 456 Ave",
              first_name: "jane",
              last_name: "doe"
             }];

//Adds the new leads to the state
function handleRecieveLeads (state, leads) {
    return state.set('leads', Immutable.List(leads));
}

var newState = handleRecieveLeads(state, leads);
console.log(newState.toJS())

//sample lead to save
var saveLeads = [{document_id: "L1919191919",
                  company_name: "someComp2",
                  date_filed:"083815",
                  address:"33333 SW 333rd Ave",
                  first_name: "dallas",
                  last_name: "thomas"
                 }];

//add leads to the savedLeads
function handleSaveLead (state, lead) {
    if(!state.get('savedLeads')) {
       return state.set('savedLeads', Immutable.List(lead));
    } else {
       var savedLeads = state.get('savedLeads');
       return state.set('savedLeads', savedLeads.push(lead));
    }
}
//sample lead to save 2
var saveLeads2 = [{document_id: "L16161616",
                   company_name: "someComp3",
                   date_filed:"083815",
                   address:"444444 sw 555 Ave",
                   first_name: "crystal",
                   last_name: "mentos"
                  }];

var newState2 = handleSaveLead(newState, saveLeads);
console.log(newState2.toJS())

var newState3 = handleSaveLead(newState2, saveLeads2);
console.log(newState3.toJS())
```